# Typescript generics and class properties

Tags: typescript

I'm currently playing around with Typescript in a React project and wanted to use class properties to set the initial state, but I'm getting in some problems when using undefined values and strict null checks. Here a minimal reconstruction of my problem without any React specific code to demonstrate my problem.

```
class Component<T> {
    state: T;
}

interface Foo {
    bar: number | undefined
}

class Test extends Component<Foo> {
    state = {
        bar: undefined
    }

    test(a: number) {
        //
    }

    callTest() {
        if (this.state.bar) {
            this.test(this.state.bar) // Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
        }
    }
}
```

[TS playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Component%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20state%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20number%20%7C%20undefined%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Test%20extends%20Component%3CFoo%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20state%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20undefined%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20test(a%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20callTest()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(this.state.bar)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.test(this.state.bar)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

So this error only appears if strict null checks are enabled.

Also:

- If I set the state in the constructor and not via a class property
  there is no error. [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Component%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20state%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20number%20%7C%20undefined%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Test%20extends%20Component%3CFoo%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.state%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20undefined%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20test(a%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20callTest()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(this.state.bar)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.test(this.state.bar)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)
- If I set type explicitly on the class property there is no error. [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Component%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20state%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20number%20%7C%20undefined%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Test%20extends%20Component%3CFoo%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20state%3A%20Foo%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20undefined%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20test(a%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20callTest()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(this.state.bar)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.test(this.state.bar)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

So is this a case Typescript is not handling well or am I missing something / doing something wrong?

EDIT: so as it appears the TS-playground does't share the options so please manually check sctrictNullChecks to see the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you redeclare the `state` property in `Test`, it gets a new type based on the type of the initializer, namely `{bar: undefined}`, as you can see by hovering over `state`.  This is why TypeScript thinks that `this.state.bar` can't be anything other than `undefined`, even after you checked that it was truthy.  Initializing the `state` in the constructor is the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

Because `undefined` is treated as a standalone type in Typescript. You're passing an `undefined` to a argument with type `number` of the test function. If you're sure that your test function may accept an `undefined`, simply allow `undefined` as a acceptable argument type:

```
test(a: number | undefined) {
        //
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, sorry but this is not a way I want to go. First this does't explain why the code works if I initialize the state in the constructor. Second `test` could be an external function I have no influence on.

Comment: @giggo1604 Could you share your constructor in that case? And if `test` is an external function, I think one option is to do the null check before passing the argument to `test`.

Comment: updated the original post, please take note of the edit comment. thanks for your help